# How do I flip and rotate a label at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, cgaffinetransform

So I have been working on this project for a while now and it requires me to rotate and flip a label.

Here is what I have:

```
@IBAction func Flip(_ sender: Any) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0,animations: {
        self.timeLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
        self.timeLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (-90 * .pi / 180.0)
```

I expected to have the label flipped(mirrored) and then rotated when I tap the button"Flip", but the result in the simulator was the rotate only, not the flip.

It would be great if someone could rewrite this code for me so it could do both. I'm pretty new and it seems as though this project will take a while.

Comment: You have to concatenate the two transform together and then set the transform property once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rmaddy has suggested, prepare two transform separately, concat them together which ends up creating a single transformation, then assign it woulf look like

```
let flipping = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
let rotating = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (-90 * .pi / 180.0)
let fullTransformation = flipping.concatenating(rotating)
self.timeLabel.transform = fullTransformation
```

For more info on the `concatenating`, check the doc following
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform/1455996-concatenating

Comment: Do I put this under an an action, so that when I press it, the label will flip and rotate at the same time?

Comment: Yes, you put it inside the @IBAction method of flip button to achieve the result.

Comment: @JoshuaCJG You replace your two existing lines to set the transform with the lines in this answer.